# How can I view the full `package-alist` value (without the truncation characters "...")?

Tags: scratch-buffer, sexp

When I do `C-h v package-alist`, I see something like

```el
((PACKAGE-NAME1 [cl-struct-package-desc
                PACKAGE-NAME1
                (VERSION1)
                "DESCRIPTION1"
                (DEPENDENCIES-ALIST1)
                nil
                nil
                "LOCAL-INST-PATH1"
                (URL-ALIST1)
                nil])

 (PACKAGE-NAME2 [cl-struct-package-desc
                PACKAGE-NAME2
                (VERSION2)
                "DESCRIPTION2"
                (DEPENDENCIES-ALIST2)
                nil
                nil
                "LOCAL-INST-PATH2"
                (URL-ALIST2)
                nil])
  ...)
```

How can I see the **full** alist instead of its truncated form with the ellipsis characters `...` at the end?

Comment: I've got `eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expression-print-level` both at `nil` for this reason. It can be a pain though if something too large is printed.

Comment: You can also press `RET` on the ellipsis to expand it. I usually press `RET` and then yank-paste it. There's also a way to cancel the special overlay that hides the rest of the printed text with one function, but I think one would have to write it. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568262

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can tweak *eval-expression-print-** or expand by hitting *RET* or *mouse-2* on the ellipses (which calls *last-sexp-toggle-display*). However probably the most useful for general messing around in the **scratch** buffer is:

```
(pp package-alist)
```

Which will format the output in a more readable way.

Answer (score 6):

Set [`eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expression-print-level`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html) to `nil`.