# Lisp form print depth

Tags: print

What controls the print depth of lisp forms? For example:

```el
(macroexpand '(defun foo () (let ((bar)) (+ 1 2))))
```

becomes

```
(defalias (quote foo) (function (lambda nil (let ... ...))))
```

in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: See the variables `eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expression-print-level `.  Here is a semi-related thread:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/how-can-i-view-the-full-package-alist-value-without-the-truncation-characters/7983#7983

Comment: Thanks; those led me to the ones I was *really* looking for, `print-length` and `print-level`.

Comment: One of you: Please post the answer as an answer, so the question does not remain "unanswered". Thx.

Comment: It says I can do that in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print length/depth for the echo area are in `eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expresssion-print-depth` respectively.

For general printing (e.g. `princ`), the relevant variables are `print-length` and `print-level`.