# How to expand truncated information displayed in the echo area?

Tags: echo-area

I am reading the Elisp Reference Manual. I have noticed that some informations are truncated (*ellipsis: suspension points*) while they are displayed in the echo area. **How to view (know) their full value?**

For instance, look at the example given to introduce the function `buffer-local-variables`, [Variables, Buffer-Local Variables, Creating Buffer-Local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Creating-Buffer_002dLocal).

```
(make-local-variable 'foobar)
(makunbound 'foobar)
(make-local-variable 'bind-me)
(setq bind-me 69)
(setq lcl (buffer-local-variables))
    ;; First, built-in variables local in all buffers:
⇒ ((mark-active . nil)
    (buffer-undo-list . nil)
    (mode-name . "Fundamental")
    ...
    ;; Next, non-built-in buffer-local variables.
    ;; This one is buffer-local and void:
    foobar
    ;; This one is buffer-local and nonvoid:
    (bind-me . 69))
```

The function `buffer-local-variables` returns a list describing the local variables defined in the current buffer. Unfortunately, the echo area does not display all the variables.

```
((buffer-display-time 23545 18944 425229 321000) (buffer-display-count . 2)\
 (buffer -invisiblity-spec . t) (buffer-file-truename) (point-before-scroll)\
 (buffer-auto-save-file-format . t) (buffer-file-format) (enable-multibyte\
  -characters . t) (mark-active . t) (bidi-paragraph-direction . left-to-right)\
 (local-abbrev-table . [## 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...])\
 (mode-name . "Lisp Interaction") ...)
```

The local variables `foobar` and `bind-me` are not displayed in the echo area although they are members of the list.

```
(assoc 'bind-me lcl)
⇒ (bind-me . 69)
```

<sub>[How can I view the full `package-alist` value (without the truncation characters "...")?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7978/19761)

[What is the meaning of the ellipsis at the end of some output?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/34413/19761)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These variables may be relevant:  `eval-expression-print-level` and `eval-expression-print-length`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html

See also the variables:  `print-level` and `print-length`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html

The `*Messages*` buffer may contain more information than the minibuffer provided that the appropriate print-length is set.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when the value of those four variables is set to `nil` the messages buffer and the echo area still truncate some elements. Here's an example:

`Result: ((entries . #<hash-table equal 15093/18699 0x457c9a47>) (strings) (preamble) (comments) (local-vars) (dialect) (buffer . #<buffer  2:old.bib>) (cur-entry . "OpenPhilanthropy2014CenterBudgetPolicy") (marked-entries) (filter) (sortinfo) (filename . "/Users/pablostafforini/Dropbox/bibliography/old.bi...") (main) (keys) (modtime 25470 28718 565638 721000) (modified) (backup . t))`

Comment: Do you happen to know the name of the variable(s) that control this behavior?

Comment: @Pablo -- You may wish to consider posting a new question with a minimal working example demonstrating the problem, so that forum participants can see whether the variables mentioned hereinabove are at issue, or whether something else is at play in your particular use-case.

Comment: Makes sense—thanks. I'll post a question shortly.

Comment: I forgot to post the question, but I have now figured out the variables controlling this behavior: `edebug-print-level` and `edebug-print-length`. Hopefully this will be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The messages sent to the `echo-area` (message) in [emacs reference manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_621.html) also show in the ***messages*** buffer. see [emacs-wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MessagesBuffer):

also look:
 [Inspect message output](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29826/inspect-message-output)
[How to copy minibuffer contents?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/how-to-copy-minibuffer-contents)