# How do I get full length of echo text?

Tags: echo-area, edebug

Note: the text I want to see is generated when am in edebug mode

my output is "echo text too l..."

I want to get "echo text too long."

I try setting "eval-expression-print-maximum-character,"  "edebug-print-level", "edebug-print-length" to bigger value, but my output area echo still truncated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand truncated information displayed in the echo area?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46186/how-to-expand-truncated-information-displayed-in-the-echo-area)

Comment: I already tried all the options in the link you attached before I posted this.

Comment: Whether the answers to another question are sufficient to solve your problem doesn't speak to whether the *question* is a duplicate.

Comment: with what you mentioned in mind, how would an unanswer question get resurface? I genuinely want to know, so I know what to do.